# Why are loop spaces $\Omega Y$ examples of grouplike spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

Here is my definition for a grouplike space or an $H-$group from "Introduction to homotopy theory" by Martin Arkowitz:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

And here is a question I found here:

[Every loop space $(\Omega Y,w_0)$ has the structure of an $H$-group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755653/every-loop-space-omega-y-w-0-has-the-structure-of-an-h-group) that is answering my question which is **Why are loop spaces $\Omega Y$ examples of grouplike spaces ?**, but unfortunately I do not understand the proof in that question, so I need a proof in terms of my definition. Could anyone show me that proof, please?

Also, if anyone could explain to me how is my definition is the same as the definition given in the link above (if that is corect) I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Are you sure that your definition is different from the one used in the linked question? As far as I can tell, the question you linked only asks for a certain part of the proof (concerning part 1. in your definition) but the definition should be just the one you use.

Comment: Loop spaces are studied in detail in $\S$ 2.3 of Arkowitz. You'll find everything you need in that section.

Comment: The basic idea is all the arguments you make to prove the fundamental group is a group can be thought of on the level of spaces as proving that $\Omega Y$ is an H-group.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Ok. I will reread the linked question and see, maybe I am not understanding it.

Comment: @JustinYoung are you speaking about the fundamental group $\pi_{1}(X)$ of in topology?

Comment: @Smart20 Yes. Observe that $\pi_0(\Omega Y) = \pi_1(Y)$.